# Enviar Json con Ajax a Spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

No consigo enviar un `json` a un controlador de Spring MVC, no tengo ningún error, pero no me imprime nada el controlador, no sé en que estoy fallando.

Javascript Ajax:

```
var search = {
  "pName" : "bhanu",
  "lName" : "prasad"
}

var enviar = JSON.stringify(search);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/HelloSpringMVC/j',
  data: enviar, // Note it is important
  success: function(result) {
    // do what ever you want with data
  }
});
```

Spring MVC:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/j", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void posted(@RequestBody Search search) {
     System.out.println("Post");
     System.out.println(search.toString());
 }
```

Comment: Pero cual es el error o problema que te esta dando?

Comment: El problema es que no recibo nada en el controlador, y no se si hay algo mal en el código porque no me salta con ningún error

Comment: Creo que el problema es @RequestBody Search search, no se si así puedo recoger correctamente el Json ya que he probado con otro tipo de datos ( un String) y me ha enviado correctamente

Comment: Yo veo q te falta son los headers por lo menos deberia estar el de aplication json

Comment: he añadido los siguientes headers y sigo con el mismo problema headers : {
          'Accept' : 'application/json',
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        }, sólo consigo recibir si cambio Search por String porque podría ser?

Comment: Tu método sigue siendo void? Porque si es así no va a retornar nada, tienes que espicificar el tipo de dato. Si quieres que la respuesta sea un json, tienes que convertir el resultado (transformar de objetos a json). Por suerte, Spring usa un provider default (creo q es Jackson si no recuerdo mal) que hace esto automáticamente. Pero para que se active, tienes que anotar tu método como @ResponseBody